# Submit Form AFTER Validation

Tags: php, validation

Here's hoping this'll be a simple question.

I'm trying to validate image size/type before processing a form's content on a separate PHP page.

The validation works perfectly, redirecting to the page and processing the form, is not.

```
$image = $_FILES['files']['name'];
$ext = strrchr($_FILES['files']['name'], ".");

if (isset($_POST['submitNews'])) {
    if ($image != NULL && $_FILES["files"]["size"]<5000) {  
        if ($ext == '.png' || $ext == '.jpg') {
            $message = "Good file type";
        }
        else {
            $message = "Bad file type";
        }
    }
    elseif ($image != NULL && $_FILES["files"]["size"]>5001) {
        $message = "Too big";
    }
    else {
        //Process form
        header("Location: ../includes/manage_news.php");
    }
}

?>
```

The header redirect is not the correct solution as the form's data isn't making it to the manage_news.php page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two possibilities:

1. Make the validation part of the form submission, i.e. don't make a redirect (of course you can still keep your logic in separate files).
2. Use [**sessions**](http://php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php) to persist the POST data between the requests.

Answer (score 0):

You should refactor your code. Something like this should help out

```
if (isset($_POST['submitNews'])) {
   if (validateImage() === true) {
      //image passed validation, process form
   }
}

function validateImage() {
   $image = $_FILES['files']['name'];
   if ($image != NULL && $_FILES["files"]["size"]<5000) {  
        if ($ext == '.png' || $ext == '.jpg') {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return "Bad file type";
        }
    }
    elseif ($image != NULL && $_FILES["files"]["size"]>5001) {
        return "Too big";
    }
    return false; //or true, depends on how you want it
}
```

This is just an idea, you can adapt it to your code. I'm returning TRUE if it passes all your tests and returns the message if it doesn't pass the checks. That's why I check using `===`.